# Evaluating $\int_0^{\infty} \log\left(1-2\frac{\cos(2a)}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^4}\right)^2 \ dx, \quad 0\le a \le \pi $

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

@Did, what do you recommend me for?

$$\int_0^{\infty} \log\left(1-2\frac{\cos(2a)}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^4}\right)^2 \ dx, \quad 0\le a \le \pi $$

The integration by parts is of no help. What else is left?

@Did, what do you think about the generalization? Does it have a closed form?
$$\int_0^{\infty} \log\left(1-2\frac{\cos(2a)}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^4}\right)^n \ dx, \quad 0\le a \le \pi, \space n\ge 1, n \in \mathbb{N}  $$

Comment: I don't think you can "@" another user in a post - is this in response to some earlier suggestion from Did?

Comment: Maybe we should have an "ask-Did" tag.

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely that this has a closed form in general.  However, I can tell you that for the 
special case $\cos(2a) = 0$,

$$ \int_0^\infty \log\left(1 + \frac{1}{x^4}\right)^2\ dx = \sqrt{2} \pi (6 \ln(2)+\pi)$$